# I am facing issue in QR Code generation in django python. When i insert more than 3 objects of a class, qrcode do not work

Tags: python

Following is my QR code:

```py
def save(self,args,*kwargs):
      mylist = [self.name,self.passport,self.test_report_result]

      details = '-'.join([str(item) for item in mylist])
      qrcode_img=qrcode.make(details)
      canvas=Image.new("RGB", (300,300),"white")
      draw=ImageDraw.Draw(canvas)
      canvas.paste(qrcode_img)
      buffer=BytesIO()
      canvas.save(buffer,"PNG")
      self.barcode.save(f'{self.name}',File(buffer),save=False)
      canvas.close()
      super().save(args,*kwargs)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you use [`lincolnloop/python-qrcode`](https://github.com/lincolnloop/python-qrcode).

You are trying to paste `qrcode_img` which is larger than your `canvas`. You should use the size of `qrcode_img` while you are creating a `canvas`. Instead of:

```
canvas=Image.new("RGB", (300,300),"white")
```

use:

```
canvas = Image.new("RGB", (qrcode_img.width, qrcode_img.height), "white")
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this but do not work. However, increasing 300x300 size into 1000x1000 solved the issue.